# How to Remove Dates Gaps in amchart 4

Tags: charts, axis, amcharts, amcharts4

[image]

3

I am trying AmCharts 4 and having trouble with one small thing.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following config

‍‍‍‍`dateAxis.skipEmptyPeriods = true;`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).